# Cannot connect to samba share that is on fedora connected to ethernet switch (not connected to internet)

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, nas, samba

I currently setup a Samba share on my Fedora PC, it does show up on my Manjaro PC that is connected via an ethernet switch, but when I attempt to connect to it using Dolphin I get: Could not connect to host for smb://linux.local/

When I try to connect to it using Nautilus I get: Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused

From my googling I believe this to be caused due to the ethernet switch I am using to connect the two computers not having an internet connection. Both my PCs are being connected using Wi-Fi, then using ethernet to connect between them. Saw some posts about assigning an IP address but not sure how to go about doing that, any help is greatly appreciated!

SELinux, Firewalld, ufw are all disabled.

Comment: do you actually have a NAS or is this just two linux PCs? Some linuxs have trouble with SMBv2 or v3 out of box, so if your server is blocking SMB1, and thats all your client wants to speak, then you would get an error like the one you indicated.

Comment: Technically just two Linux PCs, how do I verify that is not the issue? @FrankThomas

Comment: well, I'd start by going over the Samba settings on both ends. what do your smb.conf's look like?

Comment: @FrankThomas This is what it looks like on the Fedora: https://pastebin.com/c3g5GZvK

Comment: Manjaro (have no shares on this): https://pastebin.com/Mk3XQ9TU

Comment: thats pretty minimal. what are the permissions on the directory being shared?

Comment: @FrankThomas I did chmod 777 on the directory

Comment: do you get any response using the IP address instead of the hostname or dropping the .local? I notice that you have the workgroup name specified differently in each system. that shouldn't really be a big deal but worth synching up. turn off wins, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: @FrankThomas how do I check what is the IP address?

Comment: in a terminal run `ifconfig` or `ip addr` and make note of the value 'inet'. some systems may require you to run these as root/sudo.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to have a guest share (no users), but it will never work until you add 'map to guest = bad user' to 'global'

Comment: My share now looks like this: https://pastebin.com/CNFxLyiJ 

Still no luck sadly

Comment: No, put 'map to guest = bad user' in the '[global]' section, NOT 'map to guest = global' in the share.

Comment: This is what it looks like now: https://pastebin.com/CCU6vCnF

Still no luck

Comment: Well it should, the only possible thing I can think of, is the hostname of your computer 'downloads' ? if it isn't, then remove the 'netbios name' line, it must be the computers short hostname in uppercase. If the 'netbios name' isn't set, then Samba will set it for you.

Comment: It isn't downloads but I removed the netbios name line and it still doesn't wanna connect. Strange.

Comment: Final thought, are you trying through dolphin or nautilus ? If so try using smbclient, I have seen reports of problems with dolphin & nautilus because of the lack of SMBv1